# flying text in a clockwise type in an image

Tags: html, image, text

I would like to know if it's possible to change a text in an image like fading out and fading in using HTML?

I would like to ask your help, I have an image and 10 text. And I would like to ask your help how to have the text flying in clockwise. Would this work with jQuery?

Comment: the image and text are in the same layer ?

Comment: This question should rather go to StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to use jQuery or some sort of javascript to get the fading part. Google for a plugin. But the text is just the tag in the image declaration:

```
<img src="url here" alt="text that  you want to display"/>
```

If that is what you are talking about.

If however you are talking about having an image of text and wanting to change that text (two another image) then jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut will do the trick: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: @Dave: thank you for the suggestion. I don't have any background about jQuery. How long will it take you to learn this? The problem is I'm not sure if jQuery will work with the CMS I'm using now. I'm using Modx

Comment: @tintincutes it is not a hard programming language as it is just javascript. If you have programming skills it will not take long at all. Have a look at the jQuery site and modify the demo.

Comment: Ahh modx hmm sorry I am a drupal person so don't really know but am sure that there would be a way to do it. All you really are doing is calling the fading routing when you hover over the image.

Comment: @Dave: Ok I will do some research about this. And will ask if there is a problem. Thanks again